# Claim with id 'alternativeSecurityId' was not found in the collection - sub journey custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an error in step 2 of a sub journey

```xml
<SubJourneys>
  <SubJourney Id="CreativeFieldSignupSignin" Type="Transfer">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
        <ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="CreativeField" />
        </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="CreativeField" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OIDC-CreativeField" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
      <!-- Attempt to find the user account in the B2C directory. -->
      <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
```

When I run the same orchestration steps in a user journey (not a sub journey), it runs without error. Is there some limitation on sub journeys where it can't access claims?

We are using the base `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError` technical profile, which references the base `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId` technical profile. I believe the line that is causing the error is

```xml
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="AlternativeSecurityId" PartnerClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" Required="true" />
```

I don't understand why our provider would return a null claim in a sub journey but not a normal user journey. The same technical profile `OIDC-CreativeField` was used in each.

Here is the `OIDC-CreativeField` profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="OIDC-CreativeField">
  <DisplayName>Test AAD</DisplayName>
  <Description>Test AAD</Description>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id">[client id]</Item>
    <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
    <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="[secret reference id]"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

We are using the base claim transformation CreateAlternativeSecurityId

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="CreateAlternativeSecurityId">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="key" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" TransformationClaimType="identityProvider" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" TransformationClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```